# Is Oot's Dream a nod to Patrick Rothfuss?

Tags: patrick-rothfuss, brandon-sanderson, tress-of-the-emerald-sea

I have recently started reading [*Tress of the Emerald Sea*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/60531406-tress-of-the-emerald-sea), by Brandon Sanderson, and in it there is a boat called *Oot's Dream*.

*Oot* is the nickname fellow fantasy author Patrick Rothfuss [calls one of his children online.](https://twitter.com/patrickrothfuss/status/1378148922296836097)

Is this an intentional reference by Brandon Sanderson, or is it complete coincidence? Has Brandon, or anyone close to him, confirmed this anywhere?